# Why do we need to separate Apply and Applicative type classes?

Tags: scala, applicative, scala-cats

I read in [cats documentation](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html) about typeclasses `Apply` and `Applicative`. I wonder why the library provides two separate type classes instead of just one type class `Applicative`, which would extend `Functor` and add `ap` ? Does anybody use `Apply` that is not `Applicative` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Applicative` provides the `pure` method, which is a way to "get in".  Otherwise, although you *could* convert `F[A]` to `F[B]`, either with `A => B` (via `map`) or `F[A => B]` (via `ap`), you don't have the capacity to put anything inside an `F`.  So you're limited to letting others do it for you.

The difference with `Applicative` is that you *can* put things in, starting from nothing.

Since either can be useful ("you are empowered to put things into an `F`" and "no, keep your hands off, and operate on what you're given"), `Applicative` and `Apply` are separate typeclasses.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it. Could you give an example of using `Apply` that is not `Applicative` (as in "keep your hands off, and operate on what you're given") ?

Comment: You can imagine all kinds of cases.  For example, if you had an error type that you wanted to process but you didn't want it to be able to generate any new errors or use any information that wasn't from an error context, you could want your error type to have an `Apply` typeclass but not an `Applicative` one.